# Почему глагольные формы на МЫЙ обычно являются прилагательными

Tags: слитно-раздельно

**Правильно ли я рассуждаю?**

1. От переходного глагола несовершенного вида «проветривать» **можно образовать** страдательное причастие настоящего времени «проветриваемый».
2. Но (по определению) эта форма  в качестве причастия должна называть  признак, **совпадающий по времени с действием глагола-сказуемого,** например:

Как часто по берегам твоим
Бродил я тихий и туманный,
Заветным умыслом томим!

Или в нашем примере: в проветриваемой мною (сейчас)  комнате становится  (сейчас) прохладно.

3. Во всех остальных случаях формы проветриваемый/непроветриваемый **являются прилагательными и обозначают качественный признак**. Обычно они относятся к помещению, в котором  (1) можно или нельзя открыть окна или (2) их просто давно не открывали (давно непроветриваемая комната).

**Некоторые примеры:**

В душной, **давно непроветриваемой** комнате содержание кислорода уменьшается незначительно, а вот уровень углекислого газа растёт довольно быстро.

Голодные дни в душной, **непроветриваемой** кладовой обессилили его (Н. А. Островский).

Тоннель Канонерского острова длинный, плохо освещенный, **непроветриваемый**, а потому заполненный выхлопными газами.

С трудом **проветриваемый** свежим ветром со стороны моря воздух здесь всегда пропитан острым, резким запахом бензина.

Ночью бобры не делали никаких попыток удрать и позволили поместить себя в **проветриваемый** оцинкованный ящик, приготовленный специально для них (М. М. Пришвин).

На вас повеет таким холодом,  вас обдаст затхлым запахом сырости и гнили, как в склепе или **непроветриваемом** погребе.

Answer (score 1):

```
  —  А это слитно надо писать (по правилу Розенталя).
  —  @Sharon Душа не приемлет! ))) 
  —  Тогда пишите раздельно, это правило мало кто знает. Ну 
     оно формальное отчасти, но без некоторого формализма в 
     орфографии не обойтись.
```

**Интересная тема!**

1. Здесь обозначено непримиримое противостояние пользователей языка и правила. Что же делать, кто-нибудь должен уступить? **Розенталь категоричен:**  пояснительными словами могут быть сущ. в Т.п., но не другие.  **Пользователи против!**

А как выразить свое несогласие? Надо доказать свою точку зрения.

2. Рассмотрим контрольное предложение: *В душной, **давно (не) проветриваемой** комнате содержание кислорода уменьшается...*

**ПРОВЕТРИТЬ**, -рю, -ришь; св. 1. что. Наполнить помещение свежим воздухом. П. спальню. П. зал. П. класс на перемене.  Проветривать, -аю, -аешь; нсв.

3. Решаем задачу отдельно для сочетания ***давно не проветриваемый.***

*Комнату давно **не проветривали**.*  Предложение односоставное, **неопределенно-личное**, субъект действия не обозначен и для нас неважен. Но мы все-таки обратим внимание на **этого субъекта**)

Это **наблюдатель за процессом**, который сам (когда-то давно)  совершал это действие в **настоящем для него времени**. Это нужно для понимания того, что  ***проветриваемый*** — это признак **действия**, совпадающий по времени с действием глагола-сказуемого.  И тогда это страдательное **причастие**, а не прилагательное.

По правилу **Розенталя** в предложении должен быть обозначен **субъект** действия, но здесь субъект действия **неопределенный**, поэтому его невозможно обозначить. Соответственно, зависимым словом можно  считать наречие созначением времени ***"давно"***. Так будет обозначена **процессуальность** признака для причастия.

4. Итак, конфликт исчерпан? Стороны примирились, сверив свои позиции с **реальностью**.

**При отсутствии** зависимых слов возможны варианты: ***не проветриваемое** сейчас помещение и ***непроветриваемое*** (вообще) помещение.*

**При наличии** зависимого слова "давно" это причастие с раздельным написанием НЕ: *давно **не проветриваемое** помещение.*

Answer (score 0):

Я не разобрался до конца в Вашей логике (ибо не вижу посылки и вывода), но тут штука такая. *Рассуждать* можно как угодно, причина-то кроется в не фиксируемых формально границах между причастием и отглагольным прилагательным.  Строго говоря, **все** страдательные причастия от глаголов несовершенного вида - наполовину, если не более, прилагательные. Различия возникают от контекста, но их тоже нельзя считать абсолютными.

Comment: В грамматике дается определение причастия настоящего времени - оно должно обозначать действие, которое протекает ОДНОВРЕМЕННО  с действием глагола-сказуемого, то естьэто должно быть реальное действие, соотнесенное с основным действием и названным производителем или орудием действия.  Вариант с давно непроветриваемой комнатой этому определению ФОРМАЛЬНО не соответствует.

Comment: Я знаю грамматику. )))

Comment: А тогда как в этом случае надо писать НЕ, это прилагательное или причастие? Знаете, мне вот кажется, что непроветриваемое помещение - это помещение без окон (качественный признак!), то есть его просто нельзя проветрить, а "давно непроветриваемое помещение"  проветрить можно,  но его давно не проветривали  и поэтому оно душное. В обоих случаях обозначено качество, а не действие, привязанное к определенному моменту времени, как в причастии настоящего времени.

Answer (score 0):

Речь-то идет о слитном/раздельном написании НЕ, верно?

> > В душной, **давно непроветриваемой** комнате содержание кислорода уменьшается незначительно...

*В давно не проветриваемой комнате*. Ее давно не проветривали, признак по действию, Людмила же не так давно объясняла. Да и отрицание здесь явно чувствуется.

Comment: Отрицание, может быть и чувствуется, но формально  по правилам Розенталя здесь должно быть слитное написание НЕ с прилагательным. Должно быть, у Розенталя тоже были какие-то мысли по этому поводу. Кстати, в текстах чаще встречается именно слитное написание: давно непроветриваемое помещение.

Comment: У Розенталя такого нет.

Comment: Из правил Розенталя: "Причастиями они (слова на МЫЙ) являются, если при них в качестве пояснительного слова употребляется творительный действующего лица, реже — творительный орудия: не любимый матерью ребёнок; движение, не тормозимое воздухом.
При наличии других пояснительных слов мы имеем дело с прилагательными на -мый (они теряют значения страдательности и приобретают качественное значение): нелюбимые в детстве игры (слово нелюбимый указывает на постоянный признак и значит примерно то же, что неприятный,  непередаваемые простыми словами чувства".

Comment: На Грамма.ру написано: иногда причастие отличается не только по зависимому слову, но и по смыслу. Думаю, здесь тот же случай.

Answer (score 0):

Не могу принять слитное написание "в давно непроветриваемой комнате". В Нацкорпусе не нашел ничего подобного, но есть противоположные примеры:

> Лязгнул засов, Варю втолкнули в полумрак, освещенный пятеркой тусклых керосиновых фонарей под сводчатым потолком, в густой, спертый воздух **никогда не проветриваемого** помещения, в шепот, стоны, тихий плач неразличимых женщин. [Борис Васильев. Дом, который построил Дед (1990-2000)]
>
> «Экую чепуху городит баба», ― подумал Василий, но что-то в ее словах как бы осветило все по-иному, комната, **давно не проветриваемая** (мать всегда боялась простуды), была знакома... [Петр Проскурин. В старых ракитах (1983)]
>
> Комнату Игоря, этот сарай, эту затхлую, **месяцами не проветриваемую** хазу, привела в порядок буквально за полчаса. [Ю. В. Трифонов. Старик (1978)]
>
> Уилер мог бы добавить, что эти совершенно лишенные солнца, с примитивной канализацией, без водопровода жилища, с воздухом, **никогда не проветриваемым**, наполненным миазмами и бактериями, грозят ежесекундно жизни их обитателей обваливающимися с потолка пластами известки, гнилыми, держащимися на «честном слове» лестницами, а зачастую и готовыми упасть стенами. [М. Оленин. Город без солнца // «Техника - молодежи», 1951]
>
> Как в спертом воздухе **давно не проветриваемой** комнаты, куда не проникает живительный луч света, ― в нашем застоявшемся стрелковом деле накопившаяся годами затхлая, удушливая атмосфера не дает вздохнуть полной грудью, мешает приступить к серьезной, ответственной работе. [М. О. Меньшиков. Хорошо ли стреляет армия? (1911.07.19)]
>
> Это недоконченный, лишенный самостоятельной жизни организм, который может водиться только в запертом наглухо и **никогда не проветриваемом** помещении. [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Дневник провинциала в Петербурге (1872)]

Comment: У Вас часть примеров с усилением отрицания (в никогда не проветриваемом помещении), это раздельное написание. Другая часть примеров относится к обособленным оборотам, а обособление способствует проявлению признака как действия.  http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77 п. 8 3) при постановке прилагательного с зависимыми словами после существительного (иногда): предприятия, не подведомственные тресту (при обособлении конструкция с прилагательным приближается по значению к причастному обороту); ср.: Шахматист играл в несвойственном ему стиле. — Это черты, не свойственные нашей молодёжи.

Comment: А это: Как в спертом воздухе давно не проветриваемой комнаты...?

Comment: А это слитно надо писать (по правилу Розенталя).

Comment: @Sharon Душа не приемлет! )))

Comment: Тогда пишите раздельно, это правило мало кто знает. Ну оно формальное отчасти, но без некоторого формализма в орфографии не обойтись.